# REST API Partial Match Pattern - Object has many-to-many and one-to-many relationships

Tags: java, spring, rest

I've got a somewhat complex domain object like such:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Boolean isActive;
    private List<Company> comapnies;
    private List<Department> departments;
    private List<Responsibility> responsibilities;
    private List<ContactInformation> contactInformation;
}
```

I want to have an endpoint in my API that will allow the ability to do an update of any of those attributes - I could add a department, a responsibility, remove a company, etc.

I don't want to do a full object update each time because of the network latency. So I will want to do a partial update (PATCH)

Right now, I have a custom data object called "UpdateUser" and that object looks like this:

```
public class UpdateUser implements Serializable {

    private User user;
    private List<Company> comapnies_to_add;
    private List<Company> comapnies_to_remove;
    private List<Department> departments_to_add;
    private List<Department> departments_to_remove;
    private List<Responsibility> responsibilities_to_add;
    private List<Responsibility> responsibilities_to_remove;
    private List<ContactInformation> contactInformation_to_add;
    private List<ContactInformation> contactInformation_to_remove;
}
```

Then the end point would essentially modularize each one of those actions (if responsibilities_to_add.length > 0, process the adding of responsibilities).

My question is more related to pattern - I feel like this is "hacky". I wish there was a way to use the partial updating to just the User object, rather than having a custom endpoint with a custom UpdateUser object. Is there a cleaner way to handle a partial update that includes one-to-many relationships, many-to-many relationships, etc.

I'm using Spring REST API libraries + Java, incase that helps.

**Edit**

I suppose this part matters also - I could easily delegate the responsibility of removing/adding objects to each of those collections in user to a different end point (I actually already have), but I wanted a single end point for the application so we could handle everything transactionally.

Comment: So you have a delegate behind the endpoint that processes logic of checking which repository methods needs to be called, correct?

Comment: That's correct - if departments_to_add is populated, I am passing that data to create the department-->user relationship

Comment: It's debatable whether it is a good idea to update a company via a user resource unless this just sets a link in the user's resource to the respective company. Usually a company is a fine resource on its own where linking to and from the user should be sufficient. I'd recommend to design the system as if you'd do it for the Web using HTML and then take the design approach and apply it as close as possible to your system.

Comment: @RomanVottner - Yeah, it's simply to generate the relationship between user and company. The naming convention is slightly confusing - but when I say "company to add" I mean "company to add to user"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a cleaner way to handle a partial update that includes one-to-many relationships, many-to-many relationships, etc.

Hard to say -- it depends on which part of the work is giving you trouble.

`PATCH`, and similarly `PUT`, express document editing semantics -- in both cases, we're requesting that the server make its representation of some resource match the client's representation.

I `GET /foo` and you in turn send me a 1GB json document.  I load that document into my json editor, and fix one or two spelling errors.  Because the changes are small, I might want to send you a PATCH request, rather than sending back 1GB of json.  That means I'll create a representation of my edits in some media type that you and I understand, and send that representation to you.

[application/json-patch+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) might be a good starting point.

The nice thing about using standards, is that so much of the work has already been done for you.  But you could instead design your own patch document schema, if you were so inclined, and publish it, and any client that understood your schema would be able to interoperate with you.

Note that this is all happening in the domain of "transferring documents over a network".  There's nothing going on here that implies the client knows that there is an object model, or relational database tables, or any sort of implementation detail like that.  That's purely the server's problem to work out.

Of course, the second part of the problem is now: here I am, a server with a patch document and eleventy tables in my relational database that may need updating.  How does that happen?  As John pointed out, that's work that has to be implemented.  One possible answer in a Java/Spring/Hibernate sort of world is that you might load your current server side state via an ORM, use the patch to guide edits into the local in memory data structure, and then ask your ORM to figure out what statements need to be run.

Answer (score 1):

I have tackled this problem in 2 ways before.

1. Like you mentioned. Having delegates that handle the logic and routes to appropriate crud repository methods
2. Use the PATCH HTTP method. Note that this is only semantic. The actual logic still needs to be done by you like any other HTTP method.

Sample here: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/http-patch